# Use a specific python binary with venv

Tags: python-3.x

According to this https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html#module-venv
'Each virtual environment has its own Python binary (**allowing creation of environments with various Python versions)**'
So how would I create a virtual environment using the venv module that has a Python 2.7 binary?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to my own question is 'you can't'
The documentation is misleading and is being changed.
See this bug that I created http://bugs.python.org/issue24356